# Do these two ranges intersect? If so, how do I know?

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation, nsrange

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1413065-nsintersectionrange?language=occ):

> Return Value A range describing the intersection of range1 and
> range2—that is, a range containing the indices that exist in both
> ranges.
>
> Discussion If the returned range’s length field is 0, then the two
> ranges don’t intersect, and the value of the location field is
> undefined.

Okay, so let's say I have two ranges:

```
(lldb) p rangeOne
(NSRange) $3 = location=11, length=4
(lldb) p rangeTwo
(NSRange) $4 = location=14, length=0
```

And I calculate the intersection:

```
NSRange intersection = NSIntersectionRange(rangeOne, rangeTwo);
```

The result is:

```
(lldb) p intersection
(NSRange) $5 = location=14, length=0
```

What am I supposed to do with that?  Length is zero, so the location is undefined?  But in this case, the result is what I would expect; can I trust it?  Is calculating the intersection of ranges where one range has a length of zero invalid?

Comment: It seems to me that a range of zero length is kind of meaningless anyway, but if you want the "intersection" in this case and don't trust NSIntersectionRange then why not just code your own.  It's a fairly trivial algorithm, if you think it through clearly.

Comment: Well, I'm dealing with text, and frequently the selected range is zero, because the insertion point is just moving about and I have no selection.  And I want to know if the insertion point is within a specific range.  Since they decided to use NSRange for all this stuff, I would have thought this would have come up.  I did code my own for my needs, but I want to understand what I don't understand here.

Comment: Does `rangeTwo` define an index?  If so, then that index is clearly within `rangeOne` and they should intersect.  Or does a range with `length` zero define no indices?

Comment: For insertion it seems to me all you want to know is whether the second point is within the first range.

Answer (score 5):

You're right. You have to go with the documentation. The value is unusable. What a hole in the API!

---

As a quick thought, similar to Tommy's answer, here is a version with a stronger promise

```
// Like NSIntersectionRange() except it returns location of NSNotFound and
// length of NSNotFound when the ranges do not intersect.
static inline NSRange MyIntersectionRange(NSRange range1, NSRange range2)
{
    if (range1.location == NSNotFound || range1.length == NSNotFound ||
        range2.location == NSNotFound || range2.length == NSNotFound)
        return NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, NSNotFound);

    NSUInteger begin1 = range1.location;
    NSUInteger end1 = range1.location + range1.length;
    NSUInteger begin2 = range2.location;
    NSUInteger end2 = range2.location + range2.length;

    if (end1 <= begin2 || end2 <= begin1)
        return NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, NSNotFound);

    NSUInteger begin = MAX(begin1, begin2);
    NSUInteger end = MIN(end1, end2);

    return NSMakeRange(begin, end - begin);
}
```

---

<strike>The returned value is the correct answer. You have a range starting at a location of 14 which has a length of 0. A length of 0 does not mean the range is invalid.</strike>

Here is an example using a length of 0.

```
NSString *x = @"abcdefg";
NSString *y = @"123";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(4, 0);
NSString *z = [x stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:y];
NSLog(@"%@", z);
```

results in

```
2014-06-27 14:29:53.610 TestApp[10501:303] abcd123efg
```

In this example, the length of 0 means the location is an insertion point and is not removing any of the existing string.

If you need a different answer, then calculate it yourself.

Comment: A range of length zero is valid, but the documentation for the intersection function specifically overloads the meaning of length zero to mean that location is invalid.

Comment: @jeffamaphone OK, I see. Wow, that's bad design on Apple's part. You have to go with the documentation, length of 0 means the result is not reliable.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I updated my answer. I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `NSIntersectionRange` exposes that information, which is absurd as they could have set `location` to `NSNotFound` or something. So you'd have to do it manually. I doubt you need the exposition, but e.g.:

```
BOOL NSRangeIntersectsRange(NSRange range1, NSRange range2)
{
    if(range1.location > range2.location + range2.length) return NO;
    if(range2.location > range1.location + range1.length) return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

(probably with a more appropriate method name prefix than `NS`)

Answer (score 1):

> If the returned range’s length field is 0, then the two ranges don’t intersect, and the value of the location field is undefined.

I'd interpret that to mean that when `length` is 0, the ranges are not intersecting.

```
BOOL RangesIntersect(NSRange range1, NSRange range2) {
    return NSIntersectionRange(range1, range2).length != 0;
}
```

Agreed with Tommy – they could have set it to NSNotFound – but instead they say the result is undefined. Furthermore, I agree that the location of a zero-length range is meaningless. The position in `rangeTwo` doesn't mean anything. Nor can `rangeTwo` intersect with anything.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug.. Your range two has 0 length so it is same as none existent... So when you do NSRange intersection = NSIntersectionRange(rangeOne, rangeTwo), of course intersection has length of 0, because you cannot intersect with something that has 0 length!!

Answer (score -3):

*"What am I supposed to do with that?"*

NSIntersectionRange is doing its job as intended. If it does not meet your needs, you can write your own.

*"Is calculating the intersection of ranges where one range has a length of zero invalid?"*

It is not invalid but is it obvious: they don't because they can't.