# Get time within radius

Tags: swift

Lets imagine we have time line with two points:

- A - start time of day
- B - end time of day

  ```
  extension Date: {
  var startOfDay: Date {
      return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
  }

  var endOfDay: Date? {
      var components = DateComponents()
      components.day = 1
      components.second = -1
      return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: startOfDay)
  }
  }
  ```

On the time line there is going one event -> it goes from specifed time, has event time stamp as an interval from 1970 ( `event.eventTimestamp` ) and there are two options :

- It doesn't have end time -> it goes out of bounds after B- point ( duration = 0, to check for it we need to use `Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) - event.eventTimeStamp`
- It does have specified end time -> We do have duration.
  In both cases It might start few days before `A` and finish few days after `B`.

How could I check whenever event is in current day -> specifed by user. After we detect this let's save in variable 24h.

```
let duration = 24 * 60 * 60

struct Event {
   var eventTimestamp: Int
   var duration: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: First one logic: `if start <= date && date < end` (whereas/where you put `<=` instead of `<` is up to you). The second one you can check the same logic as explained there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458542/do-these-two-ranges-intersect-if-so-how-do-i-know NSRange being start (same as yours), and lenght (being your duration equivalent). Now, `eventTimestamp` I'd say it's a `NSTimeInterval` instead of an `Int`, and I'd add in `Event` a property `endDate` (which can be computed from initiating the start + duration, and in other case you can compute duration from start and `endDate`)

Comment: @Larme Thank you, It has solved my problem!